# S3 PutObject Appending Query Parameters

Tags: aws-sdk-go

When using the S3 client to connect to a custom S3 endpoint it seems to append query parameters which are causing the request to fail.

When I use a putObject request using the Golang V2 SDK it sends a request structured in this way
PUT https://s3.mycustomendpoint.com/bucket-name/pkgs/myfile.extension?x-id=PutObject HTTP/1.1"

However if I make the same request with Boto3 SDK it does this:
PUT https://s3.mycustomendpoint.com/bucket-name/pkgs/myfile.extension HTTP/1.1"

The Boto3 code succeeded without issues. How can I structure my golang S3 client to not append those x-id query parameters. I have looked through all references, code and StackOverflow items I can find but have come up blank. The same happens if I use Postman to test the API call. If the parameter is added as a header entry it is fine, the issue only seems to crop up when it is appended as a query parameter.